# Фильтр на столбец Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, filter

Хочу перейти с WinForms на WPF и пока въехать вообще не могу, мне нужно фильтр на столбец DataGrid повесить, нашел вот такое [решение](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6133) и вот [такое](https://itemsfilter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20FilterDataGrid) но как его подключить к проекту вообще не понимаю. Прошу пожалуйста разъяснить. В WinForms библиотеку подключил и юзай а тут как?

Comment: @FoggyFinder мне нужно что бы в заголовке столбца была кнопка как екселе, что бы фильтровать дропдаун листом данные. Как в winforms datagridautofilter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DevExpress не использовал, а вот [проект](https://itemsfilter.codeplex.com) под второй ссылкой вполне рабочий. Единственное, автор почему-то распространяет решение через установщик ClickOnce.

Вообще, для работы достаточно единственной библиотеки **ItemsFilter.dll**. Поэтому, если не хотите запускать установщик ClickOnce, то после распаковки скачанного архива можно пройти в "Application Files\ItemsFilter.NET.Sample_1_1_0_1", взять файл *ItemsFilter.dll.deploy*  и убрать *.deploy* из имени файла, после чего добавить эту библиотеку в проект. Остальные файлы по идее относятся к дэмке от автора, их не проверял.

Ну а далее работаете как с обычным гридом, только стандартный `DataGrid` заменяете на `bsFilter:FilterDataGrid`. Добавляете заголовок:

```
xmlns:bsFilter="http://schemas.bolapansoft.com/xaml/Controls/ItemsFilter"
```

И реализуете грид, например:

```
<bsFilter:FilterDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="String" Binding="{Binding StrValue}" />

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Time" Binding="{Binding DateTimeValue}" />

    </DataGrid.Columns>

</bsFilter:FilterDataGrid>
```

... где `ItemsCollection` это коллекция (`ObservableCollection`) объектов, которые в данном примере содержат свойства `StrValue` и `DateTimeValue`.

Результат получается такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как отключить фильтрацию по определенному столбцу?